# Add UiImage in Uitextview possible to resize like page app , Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uitextview

I have One Uitextview I want to add Image like this 
and I want to Draging and change place in every where in Uitextview like Page app how can I do this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ZDh.jpg)

Here is my code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(txtEditor.bounds.size, false, 0)
        txtEditor.drawHierarchy(in: txtEditor.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let txtimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

But in this code I have one size and I can't change Uiimage size in uitextview.